# Mysql - GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES results to ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql

I have created a MySQL database "gefdb" and a user "testuser"
The user creation I have done with:

```
> CREATE USER 'testuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '********'; 
> CREATE USER 'testuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '********';
```

I login as "root" in order to grant all privileges on "gefdb" to user "testuser".

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -p

mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `gefdb`.* TO 'testuser'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'gefdb'
```

I tried to verify a few things:

```
mysql> use mysql;
mysql> SELECT user,host FROM db WHERE db='gefdb';
+----------+-----------+
| user     | host      |
+----------+-----------+
| testuser | %         |
| testuser | localhost |
+----------+-----------+

mysql> SELECT host,user,Grant_priv,Super_priv FROM mysql.user;
+-------------------+------------+------------+------------+
| host              | user       | Grant_priv | Super_priv |
+-------------------+------------+------------+------------+
| localhost         | root       | Y          | Y          |

mysql> select user(), current_user();
+----------------+----------------+
| user()         | current_user() |
+----------------+----------------+
| root@localhost | root@localhost |
+----------------+----------------+
```

I dont know why I cannot set the PRIVILEGES on gefdb to testuser. Any idea?
The problem is that I cannot use the gefdb after I login with "testuser":

```
mysql -h localhost -u testuser -p

mysql> use gefdb;
#1044 - Access denied for user 'testuser'@'localhost' to database 'gefdb'

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

It seems that the user "testuser" does not have access to the "gefdb" but I don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: This post might be exactly what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714869/error-1044-42000-access-denied-for-root-with-all-privileges

Comment: I already have read this post and tried everything they suggested but without success.