# ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'newdb'

Tags: mysql, macos, terminal

now, I can login the mysql with `mysql -uroot -p`, then I input my password.

Then I try to do this.

`mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
+--------------------+`

But when I create database, i get an error:

`mysql> CREATE DATABASE newdb;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'newdb'`

this is my grants:

`mysql> show grants;
+------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                |
+------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' |
+------------------------------------------+`

on the terminal with MacOSX.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: This question is repeated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714869/error-1044-42000-access-denied-for-root-with-all-privileges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html#grant-privileges), `GRANT USAGE` is a:

> Synonym for “no privileges”

Leaving aside the point that this privilege has a confusing name, I'm not sure how/why you have such limited privileges for root, anyway.

What you want for root is `GRANT ALL`. Even better, leave root as-is and create a different superuser with local-only access to replace root. But do note that, in general, you want to give users only the bare minimum privileges necessary for whatever they need to do.

Comment: Hw to create superuser without having any permission at all. I have tried to create a user but that also shows access denied for root user. Can you please guide me how to do that

Comment: @jayaprakashR For obvious reasons, you can't create a user (much less a superuser) if you don't have permissions. It would completely defeat the point of having permissions if you could do that.